# Redux Toolkit - actions is not called

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have this simple case:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cartItems',
  initialState: {
    cartItems: 0
  },
  reducers: {
    updateCart: (state, action) => {
      console.log('action', action.payload);
      state.cartItems = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { updateCart } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Then I try to call it:

```
updateCart(100);
```

And the *updateCart* action is not called at all. There are no errors in the console and the store is:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authSlice from './authSlice';
import tshirtsSlice from './tshirtsSlice';
import saveOrderSlice from './saveOrderSlice';
import cartSlice from './cartSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: authSlice,
    tshirts: tshirtsSlice,
    order: saveOrderSlice,
    cartItems: cartSlice,
  },
});
```

What is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using dispatch to send an action, like dispatch(updateCart(100)) ?

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't find where to import "dispatch" from.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same problem @Azu

Answer (score 1):

It's not how redux works.

In component body you need to get dispatch:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

And call with action as argument:

```
dispatch(updateCart(100))
```

To get current state you need to use selector:

```
const cartItems = useSelector(state => state.cartItems)
```

More here: [quick-start-redux](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

Comment: if you write console.log(updateCart(100)) you will see action returned by this function:

in this case: 
{
    "type": "cartItems/updateCart",
    "payload": 100
}

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have installed "react-redux", if not then install it

Then the component from where you want to dispatch an action, you have to import useDispatch first

So your component will look something like this

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { updateCart } from "./cart.js"

const func = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch()

     const updateCart = () => { 
           dispatch(updateCart(100)) 
     }

     return (
            <button onClick={updateCart}>UpdateCart</button>
     )
      
}
```

And change your store too,

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: authSlice.reducer,
    tshirts: tshirtsSlice.reducer,
    order: saveOrderSlice.reducer,
    cartItems: cartSlice.reducer,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried that and it doesn't work. In the Redux store cartItems is still 0. I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: On the console what it's printing ?

Comment: Nothing in the console.

Comment: That means your function is not getting executed at all. Otherwise it would've printed something, check your imports don't copy my code as it is because I don't know where your cart file is stored

Comment: I've checked the imports a few times. At least in the Redux store cartItems=0, which means cartSlice is called initially. But then updateCart is never called.

Comment: inside the store you have to pass your reducers like this cartItems: cartSlice.reducer. Try this and let me know if its working or not

Comment: Np, glad to help. i've updated the answer as well